# ngx-openlayer zoom to show all intesting points

Tags: angular, openlayers, openstreetmap

On our Angular 5 project we have included an openstreetmap with ngx-openlayer.
I have an Map with a list of POI's. This list can be filtered by different criteria. I want to change the zoom level so that all POI's on the list are shown.

As I have found we can use

this.map.instance.getView().fit(extent1, this.map.instance.getSize());

to do that, but I have the problem to get the correct extent for that.

```
 <aol-map #map [width]="'100%'" [height]="'100%'">
    <aol-control-defaults></aol-control-defaults>
    <aol-control-scaleline></aol-control-scaleline>
    <aol-interaction-default></aol-interaction-default>
    <aol-interaction-select (onSelect)="onClick($event)"></aol-interaction-select>
    <aol-view #view [zoom]="zoom">
      <aol-coordinate [x]="centerlong" [y]="centerlat" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
    </aol-view>
    <!-- aol-layer-tile  [postcompose]="onPostcompose" -->
    <aol-layer-tile>
      <aol-source-osm></aol-source-osm>
    </aol-layer-tile>
   <!-- List of POIs  --> 
    <aol-layer-vector [opacity]="1" (click)="onClick('Layer')">
      <aol-source-vector #source>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of api.datapoints">
          <aol-feature *ngIf="item.icon" [id]="item.uuid">
            <aol-geometry-point>
              <aol-coordinate [x]="item.longitude" [y]="item.latitude" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
            </aol-geometry-point>
            <aol-style>
              <aol-style-icon [src]="'./assets/img/'+item.icon" [anchor]="[0.5, 1]" [anchorXUnits]="'fraction'"
                              [anchorYUnits]="'fraction'" [scale]="1" [anchorOrigin]="'top-left'"></aol-style-icon>
            </aol-style>
          </aol-feature>
        </ng-container>
      </aol-source-vector>
    </aol-layer-vector>
    <aol-overlay *ngIf="this.api.datapoints.length == 0">
      <aol-coordinate
        [x]="centerlong"
        [y]="centerlat"
        [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"
      >
      </aol-coordinate>
      <aol-content>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" i18n>No data points found!</div>
      </aol-content>
    </aol-overlay>
  </aol-map>
```

On the Typescript I have try to get that needed extent over the source ( extent1 ) but it give me a extent from -infinity to infinity. I have also try to get minX, maxX, minY and maxY from my cooridnates. (extent) This will zoom deeply to the center. I think here is the problem that I need convert our coordinates from EPSG:4326 to some internal coordiantes. But how can I do that?

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiGatewayService} from '../../../service/apigateway.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-map',
  templateUrl: './data-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-map.component.css']
})
export class DataMapComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('view') view: any;
  @ViewChild('map') map: any;
  @ViewChild('source') source: any;
  centerlong = 14.8;
  centerlat = 52.50;
  zoom = 7;


  constructor(public api: ApiGatewayService) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('MAP', this.view);
  }

  updateZoom() {
    if (this.api.datapoints.length > 1) {
      console.log("updateZoom")
      let minlong = 200;
      let maxlong = -200;
      let minlat = 100;
      let maxlat = -100;
      for (const item of this.api.datapoints) {
        console.log('Item', item);
        if (item.latitude < minlat) {
          minlat = item.latitude;
        }
        if (item.latitude > maxlat) {
          maxlat = item.latitude;
        }

        if (item.longitude < minlong) {
          minlong = item.longitude;
        }
        if (item.longitude > maxlong) {
          maxlong = item.longitude;
        }

        console.log('Box', minlat, minlong, maxlat, maxlong);
      }
      this.centerlong = (minlong + maxlong) / 2;
      this.centerlat = (minlat + maxlat) / 2;

      const extent = [minlong, minlat, maxlong, maxlat];
      if (this.map.instance) {
        var extent1 = this.source.instance.getExtent();
        console.log('Set zoom level', extent1);
        this.map.instance.getView().fit(extent1,
this.map.instance.getSize());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like I need ol.proj.transformExtent(). 
But how can I access the ol.proj from ngx-openlayer?
And what is the destination cooridates system to get make the transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution.

First of all ngx-openlayer depends on openlayer, so we can also import openlayer directly:

```
import {proj} from 'openlayers';
```

So now we can call proj when we need to call ol.proj.

The Projection which is used by Openstreetmap is EPSG:3857. 
To transfer my extent to this coordiates system I will now call

```
const extent1 = proj.transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

The whole typescript as refenece:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MapEvent, proj} from 'openlayers';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {ApiGatewayService} from '../../../service/apigateway.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-map',
  templateUrl: './data-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-map.component.css']
})
export class DataMapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  subscription: Subscription;
  @ViewChild('map', {static: true}) map: any;
  centerlong = 10.447683;
  centerlat = 51.163375;

  datapoints = [];
  tempZoom = 0;
  zoom = 7;


  constructor(public api: ApiGatewayService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.api.datapointsChanged
      .subscribe(item => {
        console.log('DataMapComponent::DatapointsChanged', item);
        this.datapoints = this.api.datapoints;
        this.updateZoom();
      });
    this.updateZoom();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  onMoveEnd(e: MapEvent) {
    console.log('DataMapComponent::onMoveEnd::getZoom' + e.map.getView().getZoom());
    this.zoom = e.map.getView().getZoom();
    if (this.tempZoom > 0) {
      if (this.zoom > this.tempZoom) {
        const zoom = this.tempZoom;
        this.tempZoom = 0;
        this.zoom = zoom;
      }
    }
  }

  updateZoom() {
    console.log('DataMapComponent::updateZoom');
    if (this.api.datapoints.length > 0) {
      console.log('DataMapComponent::updateZoom::Lenght', this.api.datapoints.length);
      let minlong = 200;
      let maxlong = -200;
      let minlat = 100;
      let maxlat = -100;
      for (const item of this.api.datapoints) {
        if (this.useCoord(item.longitude, item.longitude)) {
          if (item.latitude < minlat) {
            minlat = item.latitude;
          }
          if (item.latitude > maxlat) {
            maxlat = item.latitude;
          }

          if (item.longitude < minlong) {
            minlong = item.longitude;
          }
          if (item.longitude > maxlong) {
            maxlong = item.longitude;
          }
        }
      }
      this.centerlong = (minlong + maxlong) / 2;
      this.centerlat = (minlat + maxlat) / 2;

      if (this.map.instance) {
        if (this.api.datapoints.length > 1) {
          const extent: [number, number, number, number] = [minlong, minlat, maxlong, maxlat];
          console.log('DataMapComponent::updateZoom::Extent1', extent);

          console.log('DataMapComponent::updateZoom::Map', this.map.instance);
          const extent1 = proj.transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
          // var extent1 = this.source.instance.getExtent();
          console.log('DataMapComponent::updateZoom::Extent2', extent1);
          this.map.instance.getView().fit(extent1, this.map.instance.getSize());
          this.tempZoom = 10;

        } else {
          this.map.instance.getView().setCenter(proj.transform([this.centerlong, this.centerlat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
          this.zoom = 10;
        }
      } else {
        console.log('DataMapComponent::updateZoom Map not ready!');
        setTimeout(_ => {
          this.updateZoom();
        }, 200);
      }
    }
  }

  useCoord(lat, long): boolean {
    const result = !Number.isNaN(Number(lat)) && !Number.isNaN(Number(long)) && (Number(lat) !== 0.0 || Number(long) !== 0.0);
    // console.log('DataDetailJobComponent::useCoord::lat,long,result', lat, Number.isNaN(lat), long, Number.isNaN(long), result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

And on the html code we need to listen onMoveEnd Events

```
  <aol-map #map [width]="'100%'" [height]="'100%'" (onMoveEnd)="onMoveEnd($event)">
  <aol-control-defaults > </aol-control-defaults>
  <!-- [units]="'degrees', 'imperial', 'nautical', 'metric', 'us'" -->
  <aol-control-scaleline></aol-control-scaleline>
  <aol-interaction-default></aol-interaction-default>
  <aol-view [zoom]="zoom" [maxZoom]="20">
    <aol-coordinate [x]="centerlong" [y]="centerlat" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
  </aol-view>
  <!-- aol-layer-tile  [postcompose]="onPostcompose" -->
  <aol-layer-tile [zIndex]="1">
    <aol-source-osm></aol-source-osm>
  </aol-layer-tile>
  <aol-layer-tile [zIndex]="2">
    <aol-source-osm ></aol-source-osm>
  </aol-layer-tile>
  <aol-layer-vector  [opacity]="1"  [zIndex]="3">
    <aol-source-vector>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of api.datapoints">
        <ng-container *ngIf="useCoord(item.latitude , item.longitude)">
          <aol-feature [id]="item.uuid">
            <aol-geometry-point>
              <aol-coordinate [x]="item.longitude" [y]="item.latitude" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
            </aol-geometry-point>
            <aol-style>
              <aol-style-icon [src]="'./assets/img/'+item.icon" [anchor]="[0.5, 0.5]"
                              [anchorXUnits]="'fraction'"
                              [anchorYUnits]="'fraction'" [scale]="1" [anchorOrigin]="'top-left'">
              </aol-style-icon>
            </aol-style>
          </aol-feature>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </aol-source-vector>
  </aol-layer-vector>
</aol-map>
```

Comment: @SatyaRam Yes it works with some trouble. I have updated my answer with our latest version. And one poin I need to mention: the project is 2 years old, we have use Angular 8 and ngx-openlayewr 0.8.22. I do not work on that project any more, so I do not know if it works with newer environments.

Comment: Confirm working with angular 10 and ngx-openlayers@1.0.0-next.16. This saved me a lot of time. Thank you so much ;)